# Problem with installing SQL Server 2008 SP2 on Windows XP

Tags: services, sql-server-2008, service-pack

I'm not much of a super-user but I've been struggling with this issue for hours and I hope maybe someone here will know how to assist me.
I've just installed `SQL Server 2008 Developer`, I've chosen the stand-alone server on the installation options and ran through the wizard without a problem.
I then tried to run the SP2, which I downloaded from [here](http://www.Microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8fbfc1de-d25e-4790-88b5-7dda1f1d4e17), but I'm failing one test which prevents me from continuing on.
The test is:

> "Not clustered or the cluster service is up and online".

When I click on the rule for more information it states:

> "The machine is clustered, but the cluster is not online or cannot be accessed from one of its nodes...".

I'm not sure how it came to be that the `clustering service` (whatever this might be) is up or that my machine is `clustered` because I've installed the stand-alone server.

To verify that I indeed install the stand-alone version, originally, I removed the installation and re-installed it.
Also, it might be relevant to point out that I had at some point in the past `SQL Server 2005 trial` and `SQL Server 2008 Express` installed on this machine but they were both uninstalled at the time of this installation.
I need the SP2 installation as I have a DB which I backed up on my `2008 Express` but I cannot use it now as the `Express` was with SP2 (I get a message which says that the DB was created with a newer version).

If there is any additional information which is required please don't hesitate to ask

**Update**
What I ended up doing, **as a hack**, was to uninstall the developer, reinstall the express and export the db via tasks-export scripts. 
This included the schema and the data.
Then I reinstalled the developer, created my DB, and ran the SQL file.

Answer (score 2):

This mess probably happened because of the previous versions of SQL Server that you had installed. Such Microsoft mastodons normally suffer from an insufficient uninstall process, leaving bits and pieces all over the place. So it is really not advised to install and uninstall them on the same machine. A virtual machine is preferable if you are just trying them out.

First step is to uninstall from the Control Panel all instances of SQL Server, then totally scrub out them out.
See the following articles:

[How to uninstall an instance of SQL Server 2005 manually](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/sql-server/install/uninstall-an-existing-instance-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-ver16)
[How to manually uninstall SQL Express if uninstalling from Add/Remove Programs fails](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217122235/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2005/09/13/465401.aspx)

If everything fails, try starting the cluster service, just in order to let the installation complete.

Comment: Hi harrymc, thanks a lot for your comment. I will uninstall my current installation and then go over both instructions to verify no traces are left behind. I do want to point out that I have never installed the cluster version and I don't have any clue on what is the `cluster service`. How should this service be named?

Comment: It seems to be called "Windows Cluster service" (I don't have any cluster to verify on).

Comment: Harrymc, I've gone through both links and I don't have a "Windows Cluster service" so unfortunately I'm back to square 1.

Comment: I really hate this conclusion of mine: If no other choice, reformat the disk and reinstall Windows and all applications (ouch). These big monsters of Microsoft can really louse-up Windows, so if the idea is only to try them out, then better use a virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks, but I've come up with a patch. I've uninstalled the developer version and reinstalled the express (which has SP2 included) and exported the db manually to an access file. Uninstalled and reinstalled and now I'm going to import the access to the developer. This is not for evaluation but from actual need.

Comment: Good luck, Ittai.

Answer (score 1):

One quick fix could be to make sure you don't have another folder of "Microsoft SQL Server" inside Program Files. There should be only one at a time – unless you have set up a clustered environment when you installed SQL server originally.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen due to multiple reasons:

1. Cluster is not up when SQL Setup was started (rerunning the rules won’t help).
2. If NoLMHash policy is enabled, the Logon account password should be 15 chars.

   - http://sqlactions.com/2013/04/23/sql-2008-setup-rule-not-clustered-or-the-cluster-service-is-up-and-online-failed/
   - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828861

Answer (score 0):

Or... you just need to reboot your computer.

I've just got this error for SQL Server 2012 when installing SP4 on Win 10. I've posted here in case someone else follows the same thread as me trying to fix it. This error can come up for a lot of reasons for different SQL Server versions and different service packs on different Windows versions, still to this day. It seems more bizarre when you're running a stand-alone system and have never set up or used clustering on it.

Some are "fake" problems. If the initialization of the check fails then the rule reports failure, but the rule itself didn't fail. If you're not worried, you can skip these checks by running the installation file from the command line with these added parameters: `/SkipRules=Cluster_IsOnlineIfClustered`. Presumably this will work with the other check rules; the rule strings appear in the detailed report. (See [support.microsoft.com: Skip check workaround](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/953748/error-message-when-you-install-sql-server-2008-on-a-windows-server-200).)

To diagnose the problem, click on the "View detailed report" link. It will open a local web page. Near the top of the web page there's a line "Saved to Directory". In that *folder* there is a Detail.txt file. In that text file (probably near the bottom) the actual .NET exception error message is logged.

Some people have seen WMI permission failures. This could be user admin permissions. If it's not, then this can apparently fix it: Run the following commands from an administrative command prompt. Locate this directory:

```
%systemroot%\system32\wbem
```

Run these commands in sequence & restart your setup.

```
regsvr32 cluswmi.dll
mofcomp.exe ClusWMI.mof
```

(See [MSDN: SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Fails on Rule "Not clustered or the cluster service is up and online](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e90dce7f-3215-46f1-b74c-0f95d78a2fc6/sql-server-2008-r2-sp1-fails-on-rule-not-clustered-or-the-cluster-service-is-up-and-online?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade))

I had a different error:

```
Initializing rule      : Not clustered or the cluster service is up and online.
(08) 2017-12-19 11:04:47 Slp: Rule is will be executed  : True
(08) 2017-12-19 11:04:47 Slp: Init rule target object: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Cluster.Rules.ClusterServiceFacet
(08) 2017-12-19 11:04:47 Slp: Invalid query 
(08) 2017-12-19 11:04:47 Slp:    at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
  at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Cluster.Rules.ClusterServiceFacet.Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.RulesEngineExtension.IRuleInitialize.Init(String ruleId)
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.RulesEngineExtension.RulesEngine.Execute(Boolean stopOnFailure)
(08) 2017-12-19 11:04:47 Slp: Rule initialization failed - hence the rule result is assigned as Failed
```

There was no reason given for the initialisation failure. I found somewhere else to reboot the computer, and this worked for me. I would assume there are other sources of this and similar errors. Hopefully the above will help one diagnose the error with the actual error message of the exception thrown.